# Trying to display a Primeng Datatable for each object in an array

Tags: angular, primeng, ngfor, primeng-datatable

I am trying to create a separate PrimeNG DataTable  for each object in an array of objects. I attempted to create this with an *ngFor loop to iterate through the array and assign each instance to a table. This is shown here:

ReferencePage.component.html:

```
    <div *ngFor="let freight of freights; let i = index ">

    <p-panel panelStyleClass="panelborder" header="Freight Piece {{i}}" 
    [toggleable]="true">


    <p-dataTable [value]="freight" editable="true" styleClass="headercolor" 
    [style]="{'width':'95%'}">
    <p-column field="shipper"    editable="true" header="Shipper"></p-column>
    <p-column field="packinghouse" editable="true" header="Vendor"></p-column>
    <p-column field="pustreet"    header="Street"></p-column>
    <p-column field="pucity"     header="City"></p-column>
    <p-column field="pustate" [style]="{'width':'50px'}"     header="State"></p-column>
    <p-column field="puzip"   [style]="{'width':'70px'}"     header="Zip"></p-column>
    <p-column field="pucarrier"  editable="true" header="Carrier"></p-column>
    <p-column field="pudriver"  editable="true" header="Driver"></p-column>
    <p-column field="pustatus"   editable="true" header="Status"></p-column>
    <p-column field="punumber"   editable="true" header="PU #"></p-column>
    <p-column field="region"  [style]="{'width':'60px'}"    editable="true" header="Region"></p-column>
    <p-column field="pudate"     editable="true" header="Date"></p-column>
    <p-column field="putime"   [style]="{'width':'60px'}"  editable="true" header="Time"></p-column>
    <p-column field="puappt"    editable="true" header="Appt"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>

<div class="buttons">
    <button>Problems</button>
    <button>Driver Note</button>
</div>
</p-panel>
<br/>
</div>
```

But when I do that I get the following error:
[My error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5emJ.png)

Here is my ts:

ReferencePage.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTableModule, SharedModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { OverlayPanel, PanelModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { freightpiece, manifest } from '../shipmentobject';
import { StopService } from '../DeliveryScreen/Services/stop.service';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Component({
     selector: 'referencepage',
    styleUrls: ['./ReferencePage.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './ReferencePage.component.html',
  providers: [StopService]


})

export class referencepage implements  OnInit {
  currentRefNumber: string;
  freightnumber: 0;
  tests = [1,2,3,4,5]; 
  freights: freightpiece[];

constructor(private stopservice: StopService){}

ngOnInit(){
  //currentRefNumber = router parameter
  this.currentRefNumber = '999900';
  console.log(this.currentRefNumber);
this.stopservice.search4(this.currentRefNumber)
.subscribe((res: freightpiece[]) => this.freights = res)
}

}
```

Comment: You included the DataTableModule, SharedModule in @NgModule.imports?

Comment: I included both of them. My imports file is a little messy at the moment but if you would like I can include that as well

Comment: check whatever you set as value in `<p-dataTable [value]="freight" // here freight itself should be of type array`. so by that logic freights should be an array of array ie multi dimensional array like  `freights: freightpiece[][] `

Comment: You have to have 2 dimensional array in `freights` attribute as TimeTraveler pointed out

Comment: Good point! I don't often run across those so I am little fuzzy on the syntax but I will give it a try! Thanks